# Remove external dependency from svn repo

Tags: svn, export, tortoisesvn

I was creating external dependencies in one of my repos. I made a mistake and I want to delete one of these dependencies.

I can't delete the folder because that deletes the folder from the parent project.
I'm using tortoisesvn-client and I can't find a command to achieve this, I removed the external property from the properties list but it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you've removed the property from the project, that doesn't mean the local working copy is removed. Simply delete the local working copy of the external dependency.

Comment: This is right.  I recommended that he check in the changes, because (at least, the last time i did this) Tortoise will still show the folder as versioned until then, even though you can safely delete it.

Comment: For completness' sake: If you have access to the command line, you can do `svn propedit svn:externals .` and just remove the external dependency from the file.  This is also helpful if you want to change an external dependency.

Answer (score 7):

These are the conclusions:

- Delete the external property.
- Change the name of the folder that is causing problems.
- Update the repo, the folder will be added again empty.
- Now, delete the renamed folder.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you'll want to remove the folder from the externals property (or remove the property if that's the only folder) and check in your changes.  Then you'll be able to delete the folder, which should now be unversioned.